# Download file with Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, apache, download, httpclient

what im trying to do is to download a file with httpclient. At the moment my code is the following.

```
    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(downloadURL);     


    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    if (entity != null) {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\file");
        entity.writeTo(fos);
        fos.close();
    }
```

My download URL is something like that: http://example.com/file/afz938f348dfa3

As you can see there is no extension to the file (in the url at least) however, when i go to the url with a normal browser, it does download the file "asdasdaasda.txt" or "asdasdasdsd.pdf" (the name is different from the url and the extenstion is not always the same, depends on what im trying to download).

My http response looks like this:

> Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 14:57:14 GMT Server: Apache/2.4.10
>   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="149606814324_testfile.txt"
>   Accept-Ranges: bytes Cache-Control: public, max-age=0 Last-Modified:
>   Mon, 29 May 2017 14:29:06 GMT Etag: W/"ead-15c549c4678-gzip"
>   Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8 Vary: Accept-Encoding
>   Content-Encoding: gzip Content-Length: 2554 Keep-Alive: timeout=5,
>   max=100 Connection: Keep-Alive

How can i do so my java code automatically download the file with the good name and extension in a specific folder ?

Comment: you might want [this header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) but of course it really depends on how the file is being served from the server; show a sample of the plain HTTP response received when requesting the URL or provide a valid accessible URL you are using to be able to get more help

Comment: @OvidiuDolha

Date: Mon, 29 May 2017 14:57:14 GMT  

Server: Apache/2.4.10  

Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="149606814324_testfile.txt"  

Accept-Ranges: bytes  

Cache-Control: public, max-age=0  

Last-Modified: Mon, 29 May 2017 14:29:06 GMT  

Etag: W/"ead-15c549c4678-gzip"  

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8  

Vary: Accept-Encoding  

Content-Encoding: gzip  

Content-Length: 2554  

Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100  

Connection: Keep-Alive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the file name and extension from your response's [`content-disposition` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition)

First get the header then parse it for the filename as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27226258/get-filename-from-content-disposition), i.e:

```
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
    String name = response.getFirstHeader('Content-Disposition').getValue();
    String fileName = disposition.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"([^\"]+)\".*$", "$1");
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\" + fileName);
    entity.writeTo(fos);
    fos.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, your code seems to be working fine. However i had coded a first version with this line:          String fileName = disposition.substring(disposition.indexOf("\"") + 1, disposition.lastIndexOf("\""));
 instead of     String fileName = disposition.replaceFirst("(?i)^.*filename=\"([^\"]+)\".*$", "$1");

What is the difference between the two as they seem to be both giving the same result

Comment: @retArdos Your way is simpler

Answer (score 5):

More formal way would be to use HeaderElements API:

```
    Optional<String> resolveFileName(HttpResponse response) {
        return Arrays.stream(response.getFirstHeader("Content-Disposition").getElements())
                .map(element -> element.getParameterByName("filename"))
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .map(NameValuePair::getValue)
                .findFirst();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Java 11** code to download file using `java.net.http.HttpClient`

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.http.HttpClient;
import java.net.http.HttpRequest;
import java.net.http.HttpResponse;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;
```

...

```
public static void downloadFile(String productId) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String url = "https://sameer-platform.com/v1/products/" + productId + "/download/model";

        HttpClient client = HttpClient.newHttpClient();
        HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder().uri(URI.create(url)).build();

        // Creates new File at provided location user.dir and copies the filename from Content-Disposition
        HttpResponse<Path> response = client.send(request,
                HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofFileDownload(Path.of(System.getProperty("user.dir")),
                        StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.WRITE));

        System.out.println(response.statusCode());
        System.out.println(response.headers());
        Path path = response.body();
        System.out.println("Path=" + path); // Absolute Path of downloaded file
    }
```